# How to unstage all the files and all the commits in a git repository?

Tags: git

What is the command to rollback the git repo to its empty/default state?

Comment: Just remove the .git directory.

Comment: (Your title is misleading.) Note that removing the `.git` directory also *removes your staged content*, which is **not the same** as unstaging files (which would be `git reset`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can init a new repo

```
rm -rf .git
git init
```

If you don't even want the files, just start a new repo.

PS: You might want to explain what you really want to achieve and why, as there maybe a better way to approach what you are doing.